# Library stability across different major and minor versions

Tags: rhel, c++

I'm building a shared library from my C++ code on **RHEL A.B** (Major version is A and minor version is B).

In how many of the below scenarios this shared library is guaranteed to work in a stable, reliable manner, when I copy it from **RHEL A.B** to :

I wanted to know this shared library

1. RHEL A.C where C<B.
2. RHEL A.C where C>B.
3. RHEL D.B where D>A
4. RHEL D.B where D<A.

Please refer me to the relevant documentation if possible to get more information on this.

Please note that my C++ code doesn't have any dependencies i.e. I don't link it with any external library when I build it on RHEL A.B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant documentation is [the RHEL application compatibility guide](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-abi-compatibility). Basically, the answer depends on the libraries which your own shared library depends on.

If it depends on compatibility level 2 libraries, then scenarios 1 and 2 should be fine. Scenario 2 is guaranteed to work, and scenario 1 will work unless your library somehow ends up with a dependency on something introduced in minor version B (which it shouldn’t, if it only uses documented APIs in its dependencies).

If it depends on only compatibility level 1 libraries, then all scenarios are possible, depending on specifics: compatibility with level 1 libraries is guaranteed for two major releases after the first release introducing them, so you’ll find them across three major releases.

Comment: In case of level 1 libraries(in your last para), suppose I build my library on RHEL 6.x. Is the generated so file stable in RHEL 7.x and RHEL 8.x only or will it work on RHEL 5.x and RHEL 4.x as well(scenario 4 in my question)?

Comment: That depends on the library. Ideally, you should build your library on all the major releases; I think there are tools in SCL to help with that, I’ll update my answer when I find them.